# javascript foreach with promises

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I currently have a list of javascript objects, which each one has to be sent to a rest endpoint, for example:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  const categories = [
    { id: 0, name: 'category 1',...},
    { id: 1, name: 'category 2',...},
  ]

  categories.forEach(category => {
    axios.post('/mock/category', category)
    .then(response => persistInDatabase(category.id, response.id))
    .catch(error => console.log("ERROR", error))
  }
  ...    
  next();
})
```

my problem is that the next() function is executing before the for loop ends processiong all the posts to the endpoints and I need to wait for it to finish. Any ideas on how to develop this? I'm cracking my head open but can't seem to resolve it

**EDIT:** if using Promise.all I would lose the relationship between category.id and the corresponding response.id that I need to persist in database

**EDIT 2:** showing Promise.allSettled version (instead of Promise.all) cause I didn't want it to stop on a rejection:

```
  Promise.allSettled(categories.map(category => axios.post('/mock/category', category))
  .then(results => {
    results.forEach(result => {
      if(result.status === 'rejected') persistErrorInDatabase(**category??**.id, result.reason.response.statusText);
      else persistInDatabase(**category??**.id, response.id)); 
    })
    next();
  })
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `Promise.all` to check that all your promises in an array has been resolved/rejected before calling `next()`

Comment: `axios.post()` is asynchronous.

Comment: @Terry can't use Promise.all cause I would lose the relationship between category.id and the corresponding response.id, any other ideas since its been closed my question?

Comment: @Dieguinho no, you don't lose anything? Can you show us how you tried to use `Promise.all`?

Comment: @Dieguinho Promise.all does not change anything. If you are losing the relationship between category.id and response.id that is caused by forEach. If forEach does not cause you to lose the relationship then you can Promise.all the return value of the function you pass to forEach. Of course, forEach does not return anything. So replace forEach with map which will return an array of all your axios calls, then add the `return` keyword: `return axios.post(...` then Promise.all the result to wait for everything to complete: `Promise.all(categories.map(category => { return axios.post(...`.

Comment: @Bergi I've updated the post with Promise.allSettled as using Promise.all would break when the first one is rejected

Comment: @slebetman I know, but using foreach I still have which category corresponds to the current response. I've updated the post with the example using Promise.allSettled. What I mean is that inside the then clause of Promise.all(settled) you only get the result from axios, you don't have the corresponding category associated with each response

Comment: You don't process the result inside the `then` of Promise.all. You process the result in the `then` of map (the forEach replacement). The purpose of the Promise.all.then is to allow you to call `next()` when everything is complete.

Comment: What you are supposed to do: `Promise.all(categories.map(category => axios.post().then(result => processResult(category,result)))).then(next)`

Comment: Of course, if you want you can also process all the result when complete: `Promise.all(categories.map(category => axios.post().then(result => {return [category,result]}))).then(categoryResult => ...`

Comment: @slebetman mmmm ok... I'm failing to see the promise returned inside the then clause. So essentially you are using the promise returned by axios for the Promise.all and for the .then clause? ins't the promise comsumed by the `.then(result => processResult(category, result))` ?

Comment: @Dieguinho A .then always returns a promise. That is what makes promises chainable. A consumed promise is still a promise that can be re-consumed - the `.then()` allows you to change what is returned by each stage of the promise chain

Comment: @Dieguinho That is why I told you to add the `return` keyword so that you can re-consume the axios `.then()`

Comment: @slebetman thanks! finally got it working, it does mess my head a little, but its working!